# Cakephp automated validation generation from MySQL database constraints

Tags: database, validation, cakephp, constraints

I'm looking for an easy solution to generate automatically the validation rules in the model from the database constraints in Cakephp because I don't want to make that all by hand with cake bake. So e.g. if there is a NOT NULL constraint for a field in the database it should create a "not empty" validation rule for the field.

So is there a tool that can do this sort of thing?

Answer (score 3):

CakePHP does not support this by default, but I like the idea.

But you could implement that by <strike>overloading AppModel::__construct()</strike>, adding code into the AppModel::beforeValidate() callback, load the schema by using CakeSchema for the table the model is using and loop over the schema it returns and build rules on the fly and set them to $this->validate.

If you don't want a specific model do it you could add another property like boolean autoValidationRules. Also check if notEmpty is not already set and don't overwrite it automatically or merge it, depends on your needs.

**Edit: Try this behavior**, I just hacked it together because I like the idea. Going to add an unit test later tonight.

https://github.com/burzum/BzUtils/blob/develop/Model/Behavior/AutoValidateBehavior.php

Comment: beforeValidate might be a better suggestion (or a behavior implementing beforeValidate) - I.e. don't do anything until it's required to do so. +1.

Comment: True, for some reason the constructor was the first thing that came up for me when I read this.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed there is no built-in feature in CakePHP for this.

Otherwise if you don't want to use the console, you can use an online tool that allows you to design your applications : Models, relations and validations rules, and then automatically generate a SQL file with the right constraints on columns, your Models with the corresponding validation rules for fields, Controllers and Views : [Online Cake Bake](http://patisserie.keensoftware.com/en/cakes/bake).

You do not get to do exactly what you want, but at least you get to design your database's constraints and your validation rules at the same time which saves a lot of time.